# How to remove only one row among duplicate rows in a datatable

Tags: vb.net

I've a datatable `dtPackageTest` with following rows in it

```
testid  testname
------  -----------
1        abc
2        xyz
1        abc
2        xyz
```

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7688999/3682599) to but it removes all the duplicate rows, and my expected output is

```
testid  testname
------  -----------
1        abc
2        xyz
```

My code:

```
 Dim tblDups = From r In dtPackageTest _
                      Group By Dups = New With {Key .testid = CInt(r("testid")), Key .test = CStr(r("test"))} Into Group _
                      Where (Group.Count > 1) _
                      Select Dups
        Dim dupRowList = (From r In dtPackageTest _
                          Join dupRow In tblDups _
                          On dupRow.testid Equals CInt(r("testid")) _
                          And dupRow.test Equals CStr(r("test")) _
                          Select r).ToList()
        For Each dup In dupRowList
            dtPackageTest.Rows.Remove(dup)
        Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following changes in your existing code,this will work as you expected :
(*I guess this should be an old school logic but it works* )

```
'Add order by  - Order By Dups.testid
        Dim tblDups = From r In dtPackageTest _
                      Group By Dups = New With {Key .testid = CInt(r("testid")), Key .test = CStr(r("test"))} Into Group _
                      Where (Group.Count > 1) Order By Dups.testid _
                      Select Dups

        'Add order by  - Order By r("testid")
        Dim dupRowList = (From r In dtPackageTest _
                          Join dupRow In tblDups _
                          On dupRow.testid Equals CInt(r("testid")) _
                          And dupRow.test Equals CStr(r("test")) Order By r("testid") _
                          Select r).ToList()


        Dim id As Integer = 0
        For Each dup In dupRowList
            'Checking for testid is already removed or not
            If id <> dup("testid") Then
                id = dup("testid")
                dtPackageTest.Rows.Remove(dup)
            End If
        Next
```